# Disable UltraGrid splitter effect

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I have an `UltraWinGrid` in my project and I need to stop the user creating a "mirror" split (hard to explain, so image attached)

[image]

This was done by clicking and dragging the small rectangle above the scroll bar - is this an extra band being created?

How do I disable the ability to do this?

Comment: In [How to disable SplitterBar in WinGrid](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-windows-forms/20492/how-to-disable-splitterbar-in-wingrid) I found a message from user "Chethan Shetty" saying "In the UltraWinGrid Designer, under 'Basic Settings', choose 'feature picker'. you will get a tree where you could choose and set properties on the grid. In that, under 'Scrolling', you will notice two check boxes, 'Show Row Region Splitter' and 'Show Column Region Splitter'..." Does that help?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: If you felt like it, you could make your own answer to this question, perhaps adding some screen shots to show where the relevant check boxes are. It could be useful to future readers.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks, I've added this now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AndrewMorton in the comments. This is the guide for correcting this issue, should anyone else face this in the future.

1) Go to the form design view and click the "Start" button on the `UltraWinGrid`
[image]

2) Click on "Feature Picker" at the resulting window.

[image]

3) Finally, find the "Scrolling" options and expand this, and untick the two `CheckBox` options under "Scroll Style".

[image]

Save the changes and test and you should find that the issue is resolved.